# Rename of procedure does not reflected to code when i rename using GUI IN SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rename

I have changed the name of a stored procedure in SQL Server using the GUI and it changed, but whenever I try to modify procedure code with `sp_helptext`, in the query editor, it was showing the old procedure name.

How to get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this definition is being updated only when you run ALTER statement..

Do not use use sp_helptext for scripting!

If you want to modify the procedure code, use SSMS GUI: right click on procedure > alter to > new query. 
Or use one the following to acquire the defition from T-SQL:

```
select object_definition(object_id('uspTestProc'))
select * from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('uspTestProc')
```

Apart from the problem you're experiencing, in [sp_help docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you can read about sp_help result: "Each row contains 255 characters of the Transact-SQL definition". This means that if you have lines longer than 255 character in procedure code, such line will be broken down into 255 char chunks. In best case scenario your code won't work, but if you're unlucky it will work and produce incorrect result, for example if some code that you had in a comment will be movde to new line and become uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming Procedure names in SQL Server is not a good option as it does not update the procedure text.
Avoid renaming procedures and prefer DROP and CREATE.

Comment: and one more doubt is same happens in database rename and table rename.how the rename process occurs...